# What's the name of this shorthand in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }
```

is same as:

```
  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature:temperature});
  }
```

How do you call this shorthand?

Comment: MDN calls them "shorthand property names": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: I found the answer by googling "object property name same as value".

Comment: @meagar nd this is the first result https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 2015 provides us with this shorthand Object Initialiser called **Shorthand property names**

---

For example

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var x = { a: a, b: b, c: 'test' };
```

Can be simplified to;

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var x = { a, b, c: 'test' };
```

---

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
// Shorthand property names (ES2015)
let a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
let o = {a, b, c}

// Shorthand method names (ES2015)
let o = {
  property(parameters) {}
}

// Computed property names (ES2015)
let prop = 'foo'
let o = {
  [prop]: 'hey',
  ['b' + 'ar']: 'there'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as the **Object Properties Shorthand Notation**, although I could not find an explicit naming in the [ES2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).